# Hibernate mapping many-to-many unconventional approach

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

We are having a Java EE JPA mapping problem as described below:

1) Technologies used are hibernate (v?? maybe 2.9 or above) and oracle 11G

2) The DB architects are enforcing a very common DB structure similar to the following:

```
    COURSE        STUDENT_COURSES           STUDENT_DETAILS
    ------        ---------------           -------
    CR_PK (PK)    ST_ID (PK_1, FK_1)        ST_ID (PK) 
                  CR_ID (PK_2, FK_2)        FIRST_NAME
                  ROLE                      LAST_NAME
                                            IS_HAZED
                                            NUM_YEARS
                                            PRESENDENT_IND
                                            DRIVER_LICENSE_NO
```

3) The Java EE architect is enforcing a class hierarchy similar to the following:

```
    Interface StudentService {
       Student saveStudent(Student student);
       Student getStudent(StudentId id);
       void removeStudent(Student student);
       Set<RookieStudent> getRookies(int courseId);
       Set<SinorStudent> getSeniors(int courseId);
       JuniorStudent getStudentBodyPresedent(int courseId) (the result can be a Junior or Senior)
```

It is expected to use any approach which will implement the business service interface described above. That interface will most efficiently support the presentation layer in which the UI mockups have already been approved by our business. The remaining required class hierarchy follows:

```
    Class StudentId 
       int studentId;
       int courseId;

    Class Student
       @embededId
       StudentId id

       String role;

       String first_name;
       String last_name;
       int num_years;

    Class RookieStudent extends Student
       boolean isHazed;                      

    Class JuniorStudent extends Student
       Boolean isPresendent;               

    Class SeniorStudent extends JuniorStudent
       int age;
       String driverLicenseNumber;
```

4) The majority of the details for the students and subclasses will have to come from the STUDENT_DETAILS table.  Depending on the value of ROLE, the class will have additional attributes from that table.  For example, if ROLE = 'S', then driverLicenseNumber will be populated with the value in STUDENT_DETAILS.DRIVER_LICENSE_NO.

I have tried various mappings for this model but Hibernate's entity manager either cries about the mappings or produces incorrect results.  Is there any way to map this model using JPA? I have tried the 'single table per hierarchy' approach with a secondary table, but the produced Oracle query is totally wrong.  The query produced for getting a junior student using the business interface is similar to the following:

```
 SELECT c.course_id,
        c.student_id,
        d.first_name,
        d.last_name,
        c.role,
        d.num_years,
        d.presendent_ind,
   FROM student_courses c
        left outer join student_details d
             WITH c.course_id = d.student_id
  WHERE c.role = 'J'
```

It is easy to see how to write the correct query, however, Hibernate is struggling to understand what we are asking for. We prefer to use annotation configuration if possible.

Comment: Pressing the community with sense of urgency when asking for help isn't a nice gesture. We could not care less what's going on with your internal business, Stack Overflow is more about sharing technical knowledge in a Q&A format

Comment: Frankly, this entity design makes no sense at all to me. Either the Student entity maps a row from the student_details table, and then it can't have a courseId nor a role, or it maps a row from the student_courses table, and then it has a ManyToOne association with Course and a ManyToOne with another entity mapped to the student_details table. A given row from the student_details table can't be mapped by several different entity instances. My advice would be to map each table to an entity, and to have OneToMany/ManyToOne associations between them.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring JPA, what you are attempting to do doesn't make sense in Java. If your student goes to a different class, presumably the student's role in the new class might be different: a junior might become a senior. You can't just toggle the role change with Java objects - you must create an entirely new student instance. As JB suggested, make each table an entity. You can then use the student_course entity as a wrapper to access the attributes in Student that fit the student's role in that class. A juniorRole type would only expose fields you intended to exist in the JuniorStudent.

The Role class would use single table inheritance containing only a OneToOne to course and OneToOne to studentdetails, and use the role as the type discriminator.  The accessor methods then will access the studentDetails instead, and when you create a new Role, it can reuse existing studentDetails.  So multiple courses can have the same student enrolled with different roles without having to duplicate entries in the student_details table.